# Why is select count distinct not working in yii?

Tags: select, yii, distinct

can someone tell me why is this not working, what i mean is that the select distinct is not working its not counting properly ;

```
$count_participants = BridgeMeeting::Model()->with('idUserRegistry')->count(array(
    'condition' => 'id_meeting=:id_meeting',
    'select' => 'id_user_registry',
    'distinct' => true,
    'params' => array(
        "id_meeting" => $data->id_meeting
    ),
        ));
```

Comment: What SQL does this generate?

Comment: provide the error generated or SQL error so we can understand what is actually done.

Comment: there is no error is, it works fine it just dose not do the select distinct

Comment: I'd suggest enabling logging, and seeing if the generated SQL is what you expect: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/25766-show-sql-generated-from-cdbcriteria/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$count_participants = BridgeMeeting::Model()->with('idUserRegistry')->count(array(
    'condition' => 'id_meeting=:id_meeting',
    'select' => 'id_user_registry',
    'distinct' => true,
    'params' => array(
        ":id_meeting" => $data->id_meeting
    ),
        ));
```

The param name should also be `:id_meeting`

Comment: I really don't think this is necessary.. I don't put the `:` in my projects and all is well.

Answer (score 2):

Digging into Yii's code I figured out that the only way one can specify arbitrary column list for `count(distinct <columns>)` is to provide 'select' for CDbCriteria as follows:

```
$ar->count(
'select' => 'count(distinct <columns>)',
'condition' => ...,
'params' => ...
);
```

Comment: 'select' => 'count(distinct <columns>)' - did the trick for me when I wanted to count distinct column

Answer (score 1):

`count` [api](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#count-detail)

> public string count(mixed $condition='', array $params=array ( ))

<s>So try to pass the `params`  as an array and to the second count method's parameter.</s>

ex.

```
$count_participants = BridgeMeeting::Model()->with('idUserRegistry')->count(
    array(
        'condition' => 'id_meeting=:id_meeting',
        'select' => 'id_user_registry',
        'distinct' => true,
     ),
    array(
    "id_meeting" => $data->id_meeting
    )
 );
```

**Update:** `count` that are combined with `->with` do not work properly. A bug has to be reported.

Work Around would be:

```
                 BridgeMeeting::Model()->with('idUserRegistry')->count(
                     array(
                        'condition' => 'id_meeting=' . $data->id_meeting,
                        'select' => 'id_user_registry',
                        'distinct' => true,

                        )
                     );
```

And to debug this try to give constant instead of `$data->id_meeting`

Comment: i get this error you know what it means ? CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id_bridge_meeting`) FROM `tbl_bridge_meeting` `t` LEFT OUTER JOIN `tbl_user_registry` `idUserRegistry` ON (`t`.`id_user_registry`=`idUserRegistry`.`id_user_registry`) WHERE (id_meeting=:id_meeting)

Comment: um, You are right, It does not recognize the parameters, and I confirm this issue of yii. I will update the answer with work around. :)